# how to filter and create an response in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I am trying to maap and filter the key and value

```
  AvailblePointsToBuy = 100;
  lifePriority = { "cloth":1,"bike":2,"cycle":3 }
  availbility = {"cycle":40,"car":80,"cloth":10,"bike":50 }
```

i need to create one response based on the "lifePriority" priority and total point should not less than AvailblePointsToBuy.

```
output be like :    { "cloth":10,"bike":50 ,"cycle":40,}    based on the lifePriority need to sort with total points not to excude 100 points.
```

Comment: Use `Object.entries(lifePriority)` to get a 2-dimensional array of keys and values. Now sort it based on the 2nd element of each array (i.e. the priority). Finally, .map() the result to a new array, replacing the priority with the key's value from the availability object. Do it step by step. If you get stuck, post your attempt in the question by editing it, ideally as [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic

- Loop through `lifePriority`.
- Start fom the priority value 1. (OR minimum in list)
- Find the item from `lifePriority` with the required priority and its matching value from `availbility`.
- Add the key to the output, with value minimum of the product vailability or the total availability.
- Decrease the total availabiity as minimum of the product vailability or zero.

```js
AvailblePointsToBuy = 100;
const lifePriority = { "cloth": 1, "bike": 2, "cycle": 3 };
const availbility = { "cycle": 40, "car": 80, "cloth": 10, "bike": 50 };  
const output = {};
let priority = 1;
Object.keys(lifePriority).forEach((key) => {
  if(lifePriority[key] === priority) {
    output[key] = AvailblePointsToBuy > availbility[key] ? availbility[key] : AvailblePointsToBuy;
    AvailblePointsToBuy = (AvailblePointsToBuy - availbility[key]) > 0 ? (AvailblePointsToBuy - availbility[key]) :  0; 
  }
  priority++;
})
console.log(output);
```